# Cartographic Representation: how to use different rule for different polygon?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase, cartography, representation

I create a file geodatabase to hold a polygon of the land boundary. What I would like to set up the RULE to separate colors. I had to split the polygons into 2 separate polygons and change the ID to 2. How do I add that to the Resprentation Symbology properties ? I already have set up for the north part but need to change the color the south part.

Thanks in advance !

here is the picture I want to change the colors.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require **two Cartographic Representations** [CR] for the same layer - CR's are independent and you can assign difference colours to the same layer.

Key point 'SELECTED' Feature

> The Drawing tab shows you the representation rule as it is applied to
>   the selected feature representation. In this view, you can override
>   the representation rule for the **selected feature representation**
>   explicitly by changing the value of any property or interactively
>   using the representation editing tools.

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Understanding_the_Representation_Properties_window/008t00000042000000/